# what does these unknown request_uri values against my nginx web server mean?

Tags: security, nginx, logging, loggly

I built a web application with low traffic so far, after making some advertising I realized there are some suspicious requests against my server, this is what Loggly service shows me in panel:

[Logs from Loggly about nginx requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaglu.png)

I am not an expert in security information buy I'm suspecting that someone wants to attack my site or are preparing a future attack.

- What does these logs mean exactly?
- Should I worry too much about this behavior?
- are they using some exploit scanner software ?

I am setting a web application firewall to add some rules to DNS and changing all admin passwords but what other recommendation I must keep in mind?

Comment: Please provide an extract to your logs here, and not a link, as link tend to disappear. Also note that Stackoverflow is about software development, not about server security.

Comment: sorry, I will keep that in mind for next question

Answer (score 1):

- Yep, some person or bot is using a vulnerability scanner to poke your server.
- Unless it's excessive or causing stability issues, this is normal traffic. Every node that's accessible online will see attempts like this, and if you follow basic security practices (e.g. be up-to-date with os/app patches, use 2FA for logins, shut down unnecessary services/ports, vigilantly monitor your logs and usage, or at a bigger scale: invest in WAF, IPS/IDS products or use a vendor like Cloudflare), you shouldn't have much to worry about.
- The culprit is Jorgee Security Scanner[1][2]

[1] https://www.checkpoint.com/defense/advisories/public/2016/cpai-2016-0214.html

[2] https://blog.paranoidpenguin.net/2017/04/jorgee-goes-on-a-rampage/

Comment: thanks, that information will help me to take action on the matter, I did not thought it might be serious but I did not give the appropriated importance to the subject, I had already thought about Cloudflare and protection tools, I am going to take a look at right now